# The python code does not prints the text file 'c'

Tags: python

The code does not returns the contents of text file, instead an empty string

```
a = open('myfile.txt', 'w+')
list01 = ['content from list 01 ~']
list02 = ['content from list 02 ']
a.writelines(list01)
a.writelines(list02)
b = open('myfile.txt', 'r+')
c = b.readline()
print("This is c: ", c)
```

Comment: Don't select 2 different python version tags, because the syntax could be different

Comment: An obvious problem is that you didn't close `a` in your example. You usually should be using [`with open`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: You may think about [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to reward those how helped you, or at least comment to explain what's missing ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `writelines` doesn't effectivly writes to the file, it stays in a buffer until you call `flush` of `close`, do this easily with a `with` statement that auto-closes the file at its end

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as a:
    list01 = ['content from list 01 ~']
    list02 = ['content from list 02 ']
    a.writelines(list01)
    a.writelines(list02)

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as b:
    c = b.readline()

print("This is c: ", c)
```

---

Also use `w` and `r`, remove the `+` that isn't neede in your case, [reference on file modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function/30566011#30566011)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just by making few changes.

Instead of `w+` use    `r+`.
`r+` is use for read and write.
No need to again open the file for reading.
you can just say  `c = a.readline()`

```
a = open('myfile.txt', 'r+')
list01 = ['content from list 01 ~']
list02 = ['content from list 02 ']
a.writelines(list01)
a.writelines(list02)
c = a.readline()
print("This is c: ", c)
```

Comment: I tried to run code and found that it returns empty string for the first time it runs. second time it populates text from file.

Comment: The original code writes a new file, so in that case it will always return empty

Comment: Got it. Thank you.